# Use of BETWEEN with timestamps in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, between

I've stumbled on this page in PostgreSQL wiki, where it's advised to not use [BETWEEN with timestamps](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29):

> Why not?
>
> BETWEEN uses a closed-interval comparison: the values of both ends of
>   the specified range are included in the result.
>
> This is a particular problem with queries of the form
>
> SELECT * FROM blah WHERE timestampcol BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND
>   '2018-06-08'
>
> This will include results where the timestamp is exactly 2018-06-08
>   00:00:00.000000, but not timestamps later in that same day. So the
>   query might seem to work, but as soon as you get an entry exactly on
>   midnight, you'll end up double-counting it.

Can anyone explain how this "double-counting" can occur?

Answer (score 0):

Often when using BETWEEN, you want to use multiple ranges (in separate queries) which cumulatively cover all the data.

If the next invocation of your query uses BETWEEN '2018-06-08' AND '2018-06-015', then exact midnight of 2018-06-08 will be included in both invocations.  On the other hand, if the next one uses BETWEEN '2018-06-09' AND '2018-06-015', then all of 2018-06-08 except for exact midnight has been overlooked.  There is no easy way (using BETWEEN) to construct ranges which cover every data point once and only once.

Comment: Regarding "no easy way...", wouldn't `timestampcol >= '2018-06-01' AND timestampcol < '2018-06-08'` do the trick?

Comment: Yeah.  That was the point of the article.  I've added "(using BETWEEN)"